# vue components with the same route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have several components. This is the routes file

```
routes: [
        { path: '/members/logout', name: 'logout', component: Logout, meta: { pageTitle: 'Logout' } },
        { path: '/members/contact', name: 'contact', component: Contact, meta: {pageTitle: 'Contact'} },
        { path: '/', name: 'offline', component: LoggedOut, meta: {pageTitle: 'Logged Out'}, children: [
            { path: 'members/login', name: 'login' component: Authenticate, meta: {pageTitle: 'Authenticate'} },
            { path: 'members/signup', name: 'signup', component: Signup, meta: {pageTitle: 'Signup'} },
            { path: 'members/confirm', name: 'not-confirmed', component: NotConfirmed, meta: {pageTitle: 'NotConfirmed'} },
            { path: 'connect/callback', name: 'connect', component: Connect, meta: {pageTitle: 'Connect'} }
        ]}
]
```

On page load I'm checking to see if the user has logged or not before. If it has, I show the Login component, if not - the Signup. Everything works, but I want something else.

When I go to domain.com initially I don't want the link to switch to /members/login or /members/signup, only if the user presses a link inside the website. I want the route to remain domain.com and show the appropriate component between login or signup.

I tried with alias but that works only for one

Comment: You could just use a v-if/else or you could use a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) and route based on whether they are logged in or not.  Similar to the meta [example](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) in the docs.

Comment: how is this related to what I've asked? I want both of them to work on / and also on their routes /members/login /members/signup

Comment: I'm saying you can import both the signup and login components into your LoggedOut component and use a v-if/else to handle showing either component at the / route since you can't have two routes at one alias.